# How to generate paths from dataclass att+InitVar

Tags: python, path

I want a list of paths like this:
`'C:\\Users\\user\\PycharmProjects\\hamza\\image2py\\21706_1.png'`

I have dataclass with the att: in the code below

when i run my script i got:
`'C:\\Users\\user\\PycharmProjects\\hamza\\image2py21706_1.png'`

```
id:str
photos: str = field(init=False)
img_path: InitVar = Path("C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/hamza/image2py/")
prefix: InitVar = "_1.png"
def__post_init__(self, img_path, prefix):
    ppath = str(img_path) + self.id + str(prefix)
    self.photos = str(PureWindowsPath(ppath))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use os.sep to add the missing '\'

```
from os import sep
```

and then

```
ppath = str(img_path) + sep + self.id + str(prefix)
```